# Radio button with function Disable and Enable input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**:
Here I have a radio button and an input

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="yucho" value="Yucho"> ゆうちょ
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="UFJ" value="UFJ"> UFJ
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="Mizuho" value="Mizuho"> みずほ
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="Other" value="Other">Other
        </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unique" aria-label="Text input with radio button" disabled>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**: I want the radio button have a function that: Enable the input when clicked and Disable when clicked the other radius button

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Other").click(function () {
            $("#unique").prop("disabled", false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's not working , what should I change ?

Comment: Where is the other radio button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to disable radio button to avoid repeat clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var allOptions = $('input[name=inlineRadioOptions]')
    allOptions.click(function() {
    
        $("#unique").prop("disabled", false);
        allOptions.prop('disabled', true);
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="form-check-label">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="Other" value="Other">Other
</label>
<label class="form-check-label">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="Other2" value="Other2">Other2
</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="unique" aria-label="Text input with radio button" disabled>
```

Comment: Your code is great but some how did not work in my case. I also put your code in a seperate html and run but It did not work out

Comment: Is you radio button with multiple options? Can you show your code?

Comment: I already edited the question with full block of code , can you check it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `checkbox` not `radio`

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="Other" value="Other">Other
```

Then the script is -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#Other").click(function () {
       if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
           $("#unique").prop("disabled", true);
       } else {
           $("#unique").prop("disabled", false);
       }
   });
 });
```